# How to create a webview panel with another webview below it in vscode extension

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I was wondering if it would be possible for an extension in vscode to create a panel set up similar to this: where the main code is on the left and the extension creates two drawing panels with one above the other.
[image: MainCode[Webview] Webview]

I know that vscode has the .viewcolumn function, but I'm not sure how to get it so that the webviews are stacked on top of one another.
Currently my DrawPanel object code creates a panel this way:

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
            DrawingPanel.viewType,
            'Visualization',
            vscode.ViewColumn.Two, 
            getWebviewOptions(extensionUri),
        );
```